# Unable to run bf orchestrator function after successful installation

Tags: botframework

I am trying to use Microsoft Orchestrator functionality for combining LUIS and QnA.

Following this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-orchestrator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs

After running this command, I do not get any error of any sort.

```
npm i -g @microsoft/botframework-cli
```

But still bf commands are not running. I tried running: 'bf orchestrator' but I am getting this error -

'bf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                                              operable program or batch file.

Please help regarding this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Windows and Command Prompt, correct?

If so, check your path variable by running `path`. Mine looks something like:

```
PATH=C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\dana\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\dana\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\dana\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\dana\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\dana\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\dana\.dotnet\tools
```

The BF cli tool should be in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

So, you want to check that both the tool is in that location, and that that location is configured in path.

It might just be that you need to close and restart the shell as it hasn't loaded that path yet.

---

*Please comment and mark this answer as correct if applicable.*

Comment: Hi, yeah the bf command is now recognized, however I started getting this error now. "unable to get local issuer certificate". Have you come across this?

Comment: I have not, sorry.